# Resizing a cell with auto layout in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, autolayout

Is there any way to resize a cell in `UICollectionView` when a device changes from portrait to landscape orientation? With the new iOS 6 auto layout? I don't want to reload the whole `UICollectionView`.

I found the solution if anybody was wondering. Solution:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    
    if ([indexPath row] == 0 && ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )){
        return CGSizeMake(768, 400);
    }else if ([indexPath row] == 0 && ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
        return CGSizeMake(1024, 400);
    }

return CGSizeMake(255, 200);
```

}

So the method sizeForItemAtIndexPath specifies a width and height for each cell using CGSize. All you need to do is detect the orientation of the cell, and return the specific height you want. Keep in mind I was only changing one cell for design purposes.

After that, i called [invalidate layout] in :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
```

which basically gets the layout of every cell again, also it doesn't reload the UICollectionView's data!

Comment: You called [invalidate layout] specifically? or was it something else? invalidate isn't pulling up as a proper identifier for me.

Comment: You should post your solution below and mark it as an answer so this appears to other users as a solved issue. Thank you!